# Levenshtein distance as alternative to fulltext

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to implement the Levenshtein distance to extract words from a string.
I have a mysql table to compare every single word or mix of words.
Is this the best way to proceed or can you propose other alternatives?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried like, I think is a good solution
hope it helps